# When using Visual Studio 2015 where is the Multiple Startup Projects list stored on the HD?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When using Visual Studio 2015 where is the Multiple Startup Projects list stored on the HD?
I have a lot of projects in this solution and to test my part I only need to start some of them so I set a list and an order of projects to Start in Solution | Properties | Startup Projects | Multiple startup projects.

Every so often this list is destroyed.
I suspect a file is being overwritten during a get from the repository.
I can't find which file it is.
I do not have a .suo file which is where others threads suggest this is.

Where is the list kept so I can back up this file?

Comment: Exclude it from the list of souce management tool like, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86049/how-do-i-ignore-files-in-subversion

Comment: Exclude what?
Bearing in mind I do not have a suo file on my disk

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322983/visual-studio-not-saving-startup-project-and-solution-config

Comment: Ah it's hidden.  Thanks