# Have to set startup project every time in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, projects-and-solutions, solution

I have to set start up project every time I open this solution.

We have total five projects in one solution. Three of them are websites, one is MVC project and the other one is class library. There are lots of projects on my computer and they are not making any problem.

My other colleagues also have the same project and they don't get any problem with it. I tried to clean-build the solution but no luck. We are using tortoiseHG for deployment (even though I commit, colleagues don't have to set start up).

Please suggest where to look? I have Visual Studio 2013 Professional.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/07/29/did-you-know-how-to-select-the-startup-project-269/

Comment: My problem is that every time I have to set startup project. I know how to set it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322983/visual-studio-not-saving-startup-project-and-solution-config

Comment: @SergeyVlasov : That solved.